# get daily user retention (Hive)

Tags: hive, retention

I want to get daily user retention. (Hive)
I have the user's login history.
Based on the search date, I would like to find the number of users who accessed from D+0 to D+4 days.
(If you haven't logged in even one day, it considered to have left.)

This is my table -

| user_no  | log_date  |
| 100101   | 2023-5-10 |
| 100102   | 2023-5-10 |
| 100103   | 2023-5-10 |
| 100101   | 2023-5-11 |
| 100102   | 2023-5-11 |
| 100104   | 2023-5-11 |
| 100101   | 2023-5-12 |
| 100103   | 2023-5-12 |
| 100104   | 2023-5-12 |
| 100106   | 2023-5-13 |
| 100103   | 2023-5-13 |

....

want to get -

| log_date  | re_user   |
| 2023-5-10 |      3    |
| 2023-5-11 |      2    |
| 2023-5-12 |      1    |
| 2023-5-13 |      0    |
| 2023-5-14 |      0    |